# Как добавить шрифт в Локальное хранилище?

Tags: localstorage, шрифты, google-fonts

После подключения шрифта из Google Fonts, при переходе на другую страницу браузер заново подгружает шрифт. В это время на странице моргает текст.

Подключение шрифта AJAX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  WebFontConfig = {
    google: { families: [ 'Roboto:700,400:latin,cyrillic' ] }
  };
  (function() {
    var wf = document.createElement('script');
    wf.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
    wf.type = 'text/javascript';
    wf.async = 'true';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
  })(); </script>
```

Этот скрипт подключает:

```
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/mErvLBYg_cXG3rLvUsKT_fesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Roboto Bold'), local('Roboto-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/isZ-wbCXNKAbnjo6_TwHThJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/CWB0XYA8bzo0kSThX0UTuA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Roboto Bold'), local('Roboto-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/d-6IYplOFocCacKzxwXSOFtXRa8TVwTICgirnJhmVJw.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
```

Как добавить шрифт в Локальное хранилище, чтобы при переходе/перезагрузке страницы не моргал текст?

Answer (score 2):

Не нужно добавлять в локальное хранилище. В вашем случае проблема в том, что вы подключаете шрифт на JS. JavaScript выполняется не мгновенно (в отличие от CSS, который можно подключить еще до загрузки всего документа). Отсюда и задержка (даже если шрифт уже лежит в кэше браузера).

Вы должны подключить CSS файл со шрифтом в HEAD документа.
И Google предлагает такой вариант:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Используйте его, вместо JS.

Кроме того, подключение шрифтов можно настроить еще более тонко, с помощью этого генератора: https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: Такой способ подключения замедлит загрузку страницы полностью. Моим способом только шрифт опаздывает. Спасибо но Ваш ответ не нужен.

Comment: Сделал, там base64 надо.